# How do I reuse an object instance in an Observable chain?

Tags: system.reactive

In rx, how do you handle the need to reuse an object instance in one step in the next step? For example, I need to get a context in the ORM to then act upon. Async/Await is in the syntax below:

```
    public async Task<IList<string>> Delete(IList<string> ids)
    {
        var context = await _contextFactory.CreateContext();
        context.Set<T>().RemoveRange(
            context.Set<T>().Where(item => ids.Contains(item.Id)));
        return ids;
    }
```

An Observable version is

```
    public IObservable<string> DeleteObservable(IList<string> ids)
    {
        return ids.ToObservable()
            .Select(i =>
            {
                var context = await _contextFactory.CreateContext();
                context.Set<T>().RemoveRange(
                    context.Set<T>().Where(item => item.Id == id));
                return id;
            });
    }
```

However, I don't want to create a new context every time I delete an item. I want to create a context and then reuse it in the select. How should I do that?

Yes, in this example it would be best to also buffer and submit the ids together, but this was just an example for my question. I hope that part is not distracting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The more idiomatic way of doing it is like this:

```
public IObservable<string> DeleteObservable(IList<string> ids)
{
    return Observable.Using(
        async () => await _contextFactory.CreateContext(),
        context =>
            ids.ToObservable().Select(i =>
            {
                context.Set<T>().RemoveRange(context.Set<T>().Where(item => item.Id == i));
                return i;
            }));
}
```

The `Observable.Using` method creates a disposable resource that gets disposed when the subscription to the observable closes.

The only problem with this is that the statement `context.Set<T>().RemoveRange(context.Set<T>().Where(item => item.Id == i));` just shouldn't be inside an observable like that. Rx is about queries. Any changes should be made in a .`Subscribe` method.

What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: "Reactive Extensions (Rx) is a library for composing asynchronous and event-based programs using observable sequences and LINQ-style query operators.

Data sequences can take many forms, such as a stream of data from a file or web service, web services requests, system notifications, or a series of events such as user input."

Comment: Ugh, trying to repond on mobile and isn't cooperating.

Anyways, what do you mean by saying Rx is only for queries? As I understand it, Rx is for asynchronous programming of an application by treating all processes as data stream manipulation. Here I have a repository that takes a list of IDs, coverts them to an observable stream, removed them from the entity framework context, and returns the removed IDs as a stream. So I'm querying data in and applying operators on them to end with a stream of IDs that were removed.

Comment: A next step is to get an observable stream of IDs in rather than a list to covert to a stream. And for this operation I would want three subscribers to execute this three separate times since those subscribers are passing their own list of IDs to remove and therefore providing and opening up their own stream, no?

Comment: @Chip - Rx (operating on `IObservable<T>`) is just like Linq for Objects (operating on `IEnumerable<T>`). It is fundamentally a query language. What you do with the values that pop out of the query is up to you, but doing anything with the values that cause side-effects during the query is something to proceed with using caution.

Answer (score -1):

I think I got it and the answer keeps ended up being 'SelectMany'. I guess I'm still getting used to these operators.

```
    public IObservable<string> DeleteObservable(IList<string> ids)
    {
        return Observable
                .Return(_contextFactory)
                .SelectMany(factory => factory.CreateContext())
                .Zip(ids.ToObservable(), (dbContext, entityId) =>
        {
            dbContext.Set<T>().RemoveRange(
                dbContext.Set<T>().Where(item => item.Id == entityId));
            return entityId;
        });
    }
```

Comment: No, this isn't the correct way to do this. In fact, it seems like you're trying to do side-effects in an observable. They really are meant to be for querying data - they are deferred execution so if you have 3 subscribers then the actions are performed three times.